# Deleting row from table c#

Tags: c#, sqlanywhere

I'm brand new to c# and am trying to figure out the delete and update portion of my table.  I get the insert portion because I am not trying to select anything in my table prior to clicking a button.  With the delete and update however, I am confused as to how a query pairs up to the selected row in my table.  If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I am using a dataset and GridControl in devexpress.  I also have to make use of buttons to perform the events and will not be using the command fields within the grid.  And I'm working on making my insert with parameters.

My list:

```
public partial class PatientList : XtraForm
{
    public PatientList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PatientList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SAConnection conn = new SAConnection("dsn={SQL Anywhere 10};uid=dba;pwd=sql;databasefile=C:\\Users\\Kbaker1\\Desktop\\Training1.db;");
        SADataReader rdr = null;
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM patient";
        SADataAdapter da = new SADataAdapter(Query, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        grdList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SACommand cmd = new SACommand(Query, conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }

            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnNewPatient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Edit editPat = new Edit();
        editPat.Show();
    }

    private void btnEditPatient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Edit editPat = new Edit();
        editPat.Show();          
    }

    private void btnDeletePatient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PatientService ps = new PatientService();
        ps.DeletePatient();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

The service class performing the operations:

```
public class PatientService 
{
    public void DataAccess()
    {

    }

    public void CreatePatient(Patient patient)
    {
        SAConnection conn = new SAConnection();
        SACommand cmd = new SACommand();
        conn.ConnectionString = ("dsn={SQL Anywhere 10};uid=dba;pwd=sql;DBF=C:\\Users\\Kbaker1\\Desktop\\Training1.db;");
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO patient (patient_id, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, zipcode, phone, classification_id) 
        VALUES ('"
        + patient.PatientID + "','"
        + patient.FirstName + "','"
        + patient.LastName + "','"
        + patient.Address + "','"
        + patient.City + "','"
        + patient.State + "','"
        + patient.ZipCode + "','"
        + patient.Phone + "','"
        + patient.ClassificationID + "'); ");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

    public void UpdatePatient()
    {

    }

    public void DeletePatient()
    {
        SAConnection conn = new SAConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ("dsn={SQL Anywhere 10};uid=dba;pwd=sql;DBF=C:\\Users\\Kbaker1\\Desktop\\Training1.db;");
        conn.Open();
        SACommand cmd = new SACommand("DELETE FROM patient WHERE patient_id = @patient_id");
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: look into Entity Framework, which replaces all cumbersome T-SQL statements and gives you objects (DbContext) that you hook up to your DB. Then, manipulations is usually 2-3 lines of code. Did I say, you get IntelliSense?

Comment: The DataAdapter has a method called Update that could transfer  every change made on the grid to the underlying database. Check the docs of SADataAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `INSERT` sql statement with `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Delete:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Comment: Thanks! What about delete?

Comment: `DELETE FROM tableName WHERE something = somethingElse`.  Do you have a SQL reference you can draw from?

Comment: Robert, Is the DELETE query I have up already correct?  Thanks.

Comment: Looks right to me.  How are you populating `@patient_id`?  I would have expected a parameter in the `DeletePatient()` function, or some local member variable.

Comment: Where is defined the parameter `@patient_id`? Cannot work without that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you guys mean in regards to @patient_id.  I probably shouldn't have it as a parameter?